# Setup Mule web server and REST to SOAP proxy

Tags: mule

I'm new to Mule and am trying to setup a web server [in Mule] to "replace" an existing Java server - which simply proxies for a SOAP web service.
So:

1. Web client (js/html) requests a static resource
2. Mule Server must return the static resource

or

1. Web client uses Jquery Ajax (json) request with path starting with "api/"
2. Mule Server must forward the request to the Java server (to use the old API)

or

1. Web client uses Jquery Ajax request with path starting with "sapi/"
2. Mule Server must translate the request to XML and call the SOAP server (for new api calls)

I'm struggling to find a good starting point:

- I've played with Ajax connectors (and end-points) and can get the static content served - but not sure where to go with the api calls (don't want to force the client app to use mule.js)
- I've played with HTTP end points, and I can't get the static content served (implicit Content-Type issue)

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `http:static-resource-handler` to serve your static content: it should take care of the content types for you. See for more info: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Transport+Reference#HTTPTransportReference-ServingStaticContent%28sinceMule3.2%29
- Forget about the Ajax connector, all you need is the HTTP connector. Bind one HTTP endpoint on `api` and the other on `sapi`.
- When forwarding the request, be sure to propagate headers and, potentially, path extension after `api/`. See the example below to see how this is typically done.

  ```
  <flow name="rawProxy">
      <http:inbound-endpoint
          address="http://localhost:${http.port}/rest-proxies/raw"
          exchange-pattern="request-response" />
      <copy-properties propertyName="*" />
      <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:${http.port}/rest/#[message.inboundProperties['http.relative.path']]?#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.string']]"
  exchange-pattern="request-response" />
      <response>
          <copy-properties propertyName="*" />
      </response>
  </flow>
  ```
- If the SOAP API you're calling as a WSDL then generate a client for it and instead of transforming to XML, transform to the request object it expects.